# How to calculate "peakyness" of a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list where the elements add up to 1. How can I measure how dense (or peaky) the list is?

[1,0,0,0,0] This should have a higher density than [0.2, 0.3, 0 , 0.4, 0.1]. That is because the first list would look peakier in a histogram. The second list would vary more, there is not one element that clearly outstands the other elements.

Comment: Seems like you need to define "peakyness" before you can measure it. For example, the second lists seems to have more peaks than the first; why does it have a lower "peakyness"? Maybe regular old standard deviation is close to what you want?

Comment: I clarified the question. I don't know the proper term but I used to describe it with a histogram. So I need a function that describes how clear e.g. a distribution is.

Comment: Since the lists add up to the same value, standard deviation still describes this pretty well. `stdev([1,0,0,0,0])` is `0.447`, `stdev([0.2, 0.3, 0 , 0.4, 0.1])` is `0.158` and `stdev([0.2, .2, .2, .2, .2])` is `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function something like:

```
def peakyness(my_list):
    deviation = []
    for x in range(0, len(my_list)-1):
        deviation.append(abs(my_list[x]-my_list[x+1]))
    return (max(deviation))

>>> peakyness([1,0,0,0,0]) = 1
>>> peakyness([0.2,0.3,0,0.4 0.1]) = 0.4
```

This would essentially return the maximum difference between 2 elements of the given list, as peakyness would want an element that would differ greatest from the adjoining elements, as you said:

> there is not one element that clearly outstands the other elements

But, this would return a value of `1` when we input a list like `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`.
This list would have 3 "peaks" of 1 and 2 "valleys" of 0.
If this list is not meant to be "pointy" (your definition of pointyness is a little unclear) then one of the best options would be to use standard deviation using statistics module

```
import statistics
statistics.stdev(my_list)
```

This would return, for the list `[1,0,1,0,1]`, a value of `0.5477225575051661`

Comment: I guess I will go with the standard deviation. It tried it and it seems to be a good number how deviated the list is.